# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime when convert from string to datetime

Tags: string, datetime

I got this Error while try to convert a string to datetime "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

My string value : "09/25/2012 11:00:36:156"

Code :

```
capture = Convert.ToDateTime(newRecord.CaptureTime),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the last colon sign (':') replace with . 09/25/2012 11:00:36:156

```
        var dateString = "09/25/2012 11:00:36:156";
        var modifiedString = dateString.Substring(0, dateString.Length - 4) + "." + dateString.Substring(20);
        //var modifiedString = dateString.Substring(0, dateString.Length - 4);
        var dateValue = Convert.ToDateTime(modifiedString);
```

Comment: You mean that I have to delete milisecond part of the string ?

Comment: no I just replaces the last ':' with '.' check the modifiedString variable before Convert; if you want to remove miliseconds uncomment the other line and comment the above line

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to You use Regular Expressions. You will have validation input string and robust mechanism of DateTime convert:

```
void Main()
{
    string datestring = "09/25/2012 11:00:36:156";

    string regexpr = @"(?x)(?i)
                    (\d{1,4}) [./-]
                    (\d{1,2}) [./-]
                    (\d{1,4}) [\sT]  (\d+):(\d+):(\d+) \s? (A\.?M\.?|P\.?M\.?)?";

    DateTime capture = new DateTime(); // set to default value in case datestring isn't valid

    if (Regex.IsMatch(datestring, regexpr)
        && DateTime.TryParse(Regex.Match(datestring, regexpr).Groups[0].Value, out capture))
    {    
        // convert is succeded
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle invalid dateString
    }

    Console.WriteLine(capture);
}
```

Or [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx). Read more [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/01/05/c.net-little-wonders-the-datetime-tryparse-and-parseexact-methods.aspx).